# Does chrome understand compiled javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, javascript-engine

Instead of having V8 compile JavaScript on the fly and **then** execute it, isn't it possible to just compile the JavaScript beforehand and then embed the machine code in the page instead of embedding JavaScript in the page?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js

Comment: asm will still mean multiple compilations though right?

Comment: Won't any such machine code be architecture-dependent? It seems like a feature with minimal benefit if I need to include a compiled version for each architecture I wish to support (and then including a plain JavaScript version for other browsers that may not support machine code at all).

Comment: Not all of javascript can be compiled to machine code. Some things, like `eval` for example, means that you also need to compile a javascript compiler into either the browser or the compiled code. If you need a javascript compiler anyway, why not just use it.

Comment: The way I understand it, the V8 JavaScript engine compiles to machine code anyway so why not just do it beforehand?

Comment: Not all. Only parts that can be compiled are compiled to machine code.

Comment: There are still large parts of JS that aren't optimized either because it's hard to do so (very difficult to compile correctly) or it's impossible to do so. StackOverflow is full of questions about JS optimizations that sometimes give surprising results depending on how you write code.

Comment: If you're really wanting to run compiled code (C++, not Javascript) in a browser and Chromeland is appealing, try [NaCL](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client).

Comment: see also [Why not sending JavaScript files in browser-specific bytecode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28649467/1048572)

Comment: It looks like you can [compile Typescript into WebAssembly](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/from-typescript-to-webassembly-in-few-steps-c76f98f00632), so the short anwser is "yes"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The way I understand it, the V8 JavaScript engine compiles to machine code anyway so why not just do it beforehand?

According to the [W3C HTML5 Scripting specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#scriptingLanguages), there's no standards-based reason why a browser *couldn't* support machine code with special `type` attributes (as Chrome does with the Dart language):

> The following lists the MIME type strings that user agents must recognize, and the languages to which they refer:
>
> ```
> "application/ecmascript"
> "application/javascript"
> ...
> ```
>
> **User agents may support other MIME types for other languages...**

Currently, no browser has implemented such a feature.

I suspect the primary shortcoming of such an approach is that each chip architecture would require a machine-code version of the script compiled for it specifically. This means that in order to support three architectures, a page would need to include a compiled script three times. (And it should be included a fourth time, as plain JavaScript, as a fallback for architectures that you didn't include, or for browsers that can't/don't support compiled code.) This could significantly bloat the size of the page with data that is mostly useless. The increase in load time would seem to significantly offset or completely outweigh whatever time you save on compilation.

An architecture-independent compromise solution like bytecode seems pretty poor: you still need to include the script twice (once for the bytecode, once normally for scripts that don't support it) and you need to do some kind of run-time processing on the bytecode to turn it into machine code.

The multiple-includes-with-fallback problem is exactly why other scripting languages have not made it into the Web environment: they would need coordinated cross-vendor support to be useful. Google is trying with Dart, but it remain to be seen what degree of success they see.

Note that [Chrome does cache compiled versions of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096907/do-browsers-parse-javascript-on-every-page-load) so a script only needs to be compiled once and then the compiled code is cached for reuse when the user re-visits the page.

Comment: So does the page render differently for each computer then? Is the machine code that chrome generates unique to each computer that is compiling the javascript page?

Comment: "the machine code that chrome generates is unique to each computer" -- the JavaScript needs to be compiled to machine code that the processor understands, yes. Each JavaScript engine is compiled for a specific architecture. This does not affect the "rendering" of the page in terms of what the user sees, but it does affect what machine code is generated: you obviously can't run ARM code on an x86 processor.

Answer (score 8):

There are two main problems with shipping machine code on the web:

1. *Portability*. No server can afford providing appropriate machine code for all possible system architectures out there (present and future). E.g., V8 already supports 10 different CPU architectures.
2. *Security*. No client can afford to run random machine code on their machine without knowing if it can be trusted.

To address (1) you'd generally need to cross-compile machine code, which is more difficult and costly than compiling down from a high-level language. To address (2), you'd need to validate the machine code you receive, which is more difficult and costly than compiling a high-level language.

Machine code also tends to be much larger than high-level code, so there is a bandwidth issue as well.

Now, JavaScript may not be a particularly great choice of high-level language. But it is what we are stuck with as the language of the web.

Comment: @Hello, Nacl doesn't solve (1) (there also is PNacl, but that isn't machine code). And for (2), it does actual code validation -- but to be able to do so, the machine code must adhere to specific patterns and contain extra checks, i.e., it is not quite as efficient or unrestricted as arbitrary machine code.

Comment: I personally think this is better answer than mine (as mine does not address the significant security concern). I'll keep mine up for its spec-based explanation, but this one I think makes stronger points. (I humbly submit this to @Hello for the accept, but it's up to you.)

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: (1) Can't architecture information simply be sent in request headers and responses be architecture-specific? (2) Perhaps this can be optimized since it could work in a similar fashion to the browser and only understand code that's in accordance with web standards?

Comment: @ThreaT, re (1): that doesn't solve the problem that the server still would need to store (or generate) machine code for all possible client platforms, including any ones that occur in the future; re (2): Nacl already carefully specifies a code format, how would turning it (or something similar) into a proper standard simplify the problem?

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: (1) I don't think that's much of an issue though, the main issue here is network related, not storage related. (2) I guess you're right. Any security or standardization layer will always slow it down, yet will always be necessary unless some sort of certificate/signature process is involved that permits the use of certain scripts...

Comment: @ThreaT, it's not just the storage space, but the fact that the set of architectures you'd have to support is unbounded. And only supporting a subset, or whatever exists presently, would fundamentally break the idea of the web as a universal platform.